# memory profiling tool for application that uses C#, C++/CLI and unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, memory, c++-cli, profiler

I am working on a 64-bit application that uses C#, C++/CLI, and unmanaged C++ libraries.

I am particularly interested in finding out out the memory leaks in unmanaged code.

I have tried to use ANTS profiler - while its great for C# applications, it doesn't provide much information for memory leaks in the unmanaged code.

I know PurifyPlus is a good tool for C++ and I found out it also support .NET applications. However, unfortunately, it doesn't support 64-bit applications.

I am looking forward to see if someone has better suggestions here..

Many thanks!

Comment: If it leaks in 64-bit mode then it will leak in 32-bit mode as well.

Comment: @Hans Passant - the problem is the C++ libraries I have, have been compiled for 64 bit and so, I can only build 64 bit applications using these. And I also don't have access to C++ source code.

Answer (score 2):

If you do have source code, you may use [Visual Leak Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx).
You may however, need to Debug the .NET executable from within VC++ (DLL project). In VC++ project, along with setting the debugging target also select 'Mixed' mode debugging. This is very similar to 'Enable unmanaged debugging' in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could try AQTime which includes both .Net as well as native profilers (http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard/)

Another option is to master the Microsofts xperf tools which will surely do the job but have quite a steep learning curve. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance)